# ASP.Net Session Variables -- Setting Session Variables then Redirecting

Tags: asp.net, session

[image]

The above simplifies my situation, but highlights my dilemma -- occasionally my users are unable to access their session variables (well before the session timeout).  My configuration is as follows:

- Application is .NET Framework 3.5
- Session State is handled by *StateServer* (running locally on web server)
- StateServer service running on the web server is .NET Framework 4.0
- There is only one web server, it is not a farm or garden situation

I have a page in the flow of control that sets a session variable to an instance of a custom user object (If I binary serialize the objects to the filesystem, their size can be between 6kb and 30kb, so not small, but not very large either).  The application usually only has as many as 10 simultaneous users max.  Subsequent pages in the flow of control, check that the session variable is not null.  If the session variable is null, it is assumed that the session has timed out and the user is redirected to a "lost session" page.  I have placed (for debugging purposes) another check on that same session object in the lost session page.

What I'm seeing in the logs is very strange -- users are being sent to the lost session page, but the object does indeed exist in the session!  Is it possible that the session variable be null on PageTwo.aspx but not null on LostSession.aspx?  Is it possible that PageTwo.aspx is run too soon -- meaning the object has not yet been fully "written" to the Session StateServer?

Any ideas on how I can debug this further?

Comment: Browser specific cookie issues like IOS and navigating inside IFrame? Get Fiddler trace when it happens and see if something wrong goes on with cookies.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -- that is a good thought.  I have limited access to the web server but I will request setting a trace for a day or so to see if we can capture it happening.  I am logging every request along with the SessionID and I can see that the ID is consistent across all three requests -- does this mean the cookie was OK or not necessarily?

Comment: If you see same session ID in server side traces than cookies are fine... No other ideas :(

Comment: Could it be the write to the file system slowing you down? I usually work with session variables in memory and rarely have problems (though once in a while, we lose a session from what I suspect is a corrupted cookie, but it's never happened with enough frequency to dig deeper into it)

Comment: Also see if you can log in the session_onEnd event in Global.asax?

Comment: @Tim -- thanks, I'll see if I can write a log entry when the session ends in that event (I've read it doesn't fire for StateServer but will give it a shot).  On the filesystem writes -- I only did that once or twice so that I could get an idea of the serialized object's size -- I don't do it as a normal course of business. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: One more thing - is this something you can see on other servers, or is this specific to one server?

Comment: @Tim -- there are 3 servers:  Development, Test, and Production.  It has only ever been observed on the Production server.  Perhaps I can write a load test and run it against the Test server to see if I can recreate the error there.  I have been looking into possible differences between the servers, one thing which I don't know if it is relevant or not is that on Dev and Test the Application Pool is dedicated to my Application.  On Production the Application Pool is shared with other applications.  I don't think this should matter for StateServer sessions but perhaps it is relevant.

Comment: I have the same problem (at least when running from VS), do you have a solution yet? it didn't occur until I added a big computation into the Global.asax.cs.

Comment: I had a similar issue on one of my projects and it only happened on iphones, I forgot how I fixed it though.

Comment: removed comment about making sure no of processes in app pool was not too low - didn't see it was not a webgarden

Answer (score 0):

Because the user object exists in LostSession it should also exist in PageTwo. Since you use redirect there should be no problems with data being accessed too soon.

You could try to set a checkpoint on in PageTwo on the line where the user object is being assigned and look into the session object manually. Comparing it with PageOne and LostSession might give you a clue what causes your issue.

It is possible that the key contains a typo and thus the user object is set to null, because the key referenced has no object in the session.

Comment: Thanks @Will,  There is not a typo in the code on "Page Two".  Running it through a debugger always yields the expected results.  It also works 99 out of 100 times when running in production.  It is only occasionally when running in production that this issue occurs.  I added logging to each page that confirms the behavior.  It is contrary to the documented / expected way that Session state should work.  When time permits, I'm considering adding a try/catch and a brief Sleep so that it tries again a few seconds later.  If it persists I'll probably rebuild the servers and monitor it again.